# I want to use '$$' in dataweave in mule which will print from 1 instead of 0

Tags: mule, dataweave

This is my resultset from DB

```
{result={name=Sanjay,address=india,phone=xxxxxxxxxx},       {name=Amit,address=india,phone=xxxxxxxxxx}}
```

I want to transform as below format(xml format) with the help of transform message in mule-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resultset>
<lines>
  <line1>
     <name>Sanjay</name>
     <address>india</address>
     <phone>xxxxxxxxxx</phone>
  </line1>
  <line2>
     <name>Amit</name>
     <address>india</address>
     <phone>xxxxxxxxxx</phone>
  </line2>
</lines>
</resultset>
```

What I have done in transform message ,is like :

```
{
resultset: {
lines :{(payload.result map
"line$$" :{
name:$.name,
address:$.address,
phone:$.phone
}

)}
}
}
```

For this transformation I am getting

```
<resultset>
 <lines>
  <line0>
     <name>Sanjay</name>
     <address>india</address>
     <phone>xxxxxxxxxx</phone>
  </line0>
  <line1>
     <name>Amit</name>
     <address>india</address>
     <phone>xxxxxxxxxx</phone>
  </line1>
 </lines>
```

How to solve this problem?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
{
  resultset: {
    lines :{(payload.result map using (label = "line" ++ ($$ + 1))
        (label) : {
            name: $.name,
            address: $.address,
            phone: $.phone
        }
    )}
  }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<resultset>
<lines>
  <line1>
    <name>Sanjay</name>
    <address>india</address>
    <phone>xxxxxxxxx</phone>
  </line1>
  <line2>
    <name>Amit</name>
    <address>india</address>
    <phone>xxxxxxxxxx</phone>
  </line2>
</lines>
</resultset>
```

Answer (score 0):

This alternative also gives the same result

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
{
    resultset: {
        lines : {
            (payload.result map {
                ("line" ++ ($$ + 1)) : {
                    name: $.name,
                    address: $.address,
                    phone: $.phone
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Wrap the line structure inside the curly bracket `map { ... }`, and populate the key directly `("line" ++ ($$ + 1))`

Answer (score 0):

In Mule $$ points to current index value and just like C language this index starts from 0 so $$+1 is the only way to go about this.